# How to tell if channel is a YouTube Partner from the API?

Tags: youtube-api

There are a few features listed ( such as custom thumbnails ) in the YouTube API that require a channel to be in the YouTube Partner program.  Does anyone know of a way to determine if a channel is in the partner program from an api call?

I thought of doing a call to a feature such as branding that requires the partner program and catching an error code, but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The way i've doing is:
Getting the URL of the latest video of the channel and parse the html code getting the tag above:

```
<meta name="attribution" content="NETWORKNAME"/>
```

If the content don't have "%2user" on that string, the channel have a network, and network name is that. 
Would be nice if we had these data in the Youtube API.

Comment: That's if they are in a network I think. I'm looking to tell if they're in the YouTube partner program.

Comment: They removed this meta tag a couple of months ago... looks like the info is not public anymore

Comment: Any new method?